# Downside of "display: block" for images?

Tags: css, image, css-float, positioning, responsive-design

Is there any downside to converting `img` from inline-block elements into block objects with the `display: block` CSS property?

Most of the time, I want them to be `block` elements. Any useful `inline` aspects that I am losing? (Perhaps I am not seeing [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111136/why-is-there-a-pesky-little-space-between-img-and-other-elements) as useful?)

Should all images be converted into `block` elements by default? Why are they inline-block elements according to spec?

*P.S. I am asking this with considerations for layout via positioning & floats, and surrounding elements.*

Comment: **@Rocket**, already have — is there something you're referring to? **@Ates**, I guess that, largely, what I'm asking is — why are they deemed as inline-block elements by the spec? For example, this can stir up some problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111136/why-is-there-a-pesky-little-space-between-img-and-other-elements

Comment: in css, 'block' means taking the hold line and make a break

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well considering that a block will force anything after to line break, there is only one scenario where it would be bad:

If you plan to have another inline element (text, another image, span, etc) beside it

Comment: Thanks for engaging. That makes sense sense. From what I can tell, most websites use images as block elements primarily. I think I may start adding `img { display: block; }` to all my stylesheets. Typically I would do it on an image-to-image basis if the image caused a problem, but I think this solution is better. **Unless there are any potential 'bugs' when it comes to layout, or browser inconsistencies?**

Comment: I wish I could answer that, it use to be an issue. I can't exactly remember the issue but I believe it was an inconsistency of rendering images between browsers (IE6) that programmers had to add `display: block`

Comment: Yeah I remember something like that too... but not sure, hence why I'm asking. But it seems that this is pretty OK to do :)

Answer (score 5):

There is one downside : 
If you plan to horizontally center an image applying "text-align:center" to the parent element, you cannot display the image as block or inline-block.

Answer (score 4):

Put `img { display: block; }` in your CSS and forget about it.  In the extremely rare instance that you need something different write an exception.

Answer (score 1):

One hack found for block display:"block".

I had this image and the [wavesurfer](https://wavesurfer-js.org/) audio wave which I wanted as inline.
But, the display:"block"; in the js of wavesurfer was not allowing it.

What I did was, saved this [cdn](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.4.0/wavesurfer.min.js) file locally and changed the **display to inline** and **position to absolute** which solved my issue. The change is supposed to be done where the wave element is created.

Hope this helps someone. Thanku wavesurfer creators for such an amazing js.